# what is deny in web.config and how it works?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am confused in deny `users="?"` and deny `users="*"`. So please tell me the difference  the difference ?Please .

Comment: Seriously?  Googling "web.config deny" gave me the very link mentioned in Jamie's answer, *as the very first result*.   -1 for no freaking effort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> A question mark (?) denies anonymous users and an asterisk (*)
>   indicates that all user accounts are denied access.

Source:[Deny Element for authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aeskccd.aspx)